# How to replace multiple characters with different values?

Tags: java

I have a string, where I want to replace the characters "?" and I have an array with the values to replace.
This is my string:

```
FROM lineorder A INNER JOIN date B 
ON (B.d_datekey = A.lo_orderdate)  
WHERE 
  (A.lo_discount >= ? AND A.lo_discount <= ?) AND (A.lo_quantity < ?) 
  AND (B.d_year = ?)
```

and this is my array with values **[1, 3, 25, 1993]**.
I want to get the following result:

```
FROM lineorder A INNER JOIN date B 
ON (B.d_datekey = A.lo_orderdate)  
WHERE 
  (A.lo_discount >= 1 AND A.lo_discount <= 3) AND (A.lo_quantity < 25) 
  AND (B.d_year = 1993)
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Why is this labeled with Java tag?

Comment: You can (and should) use the query with the question marks as a prepared statement and then pass the parameters separately. Don't insert parameters directly into the query. See [the MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). Your database connector should provide a builtin way to achieve this.

Comment: if its "java", are you using JPA/Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to do it not in the JDBC way you can use string manipulation like this

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class A
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
      String s = "FROM lineorder A INNER JOIN date B ON (B.d_datekey = A.lo_orderdate)  WHERE (A.lo_discount >= ? AND A.lo_discount <= ?) AND (A.lo_quantity < ?) AND (B.d_year = ?) " ; 

      int [] a =  {1, 3, 25, 1993} ; 

      for(int i : a ) 
      {
        s = s.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("?"),Integer.toString(i)) ; 
      }

      System.out.println(s) ;      
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JDBC, and have a PreparedStatement, then you can do this:

```
String sql = "FROM lineorder A INNER JOIN date B \n" +
                        "ON (B.d_datekey = A.lo_orderdate)  \n" +
                            "WHERE \n" + "  (A.lo_discount >= ? AND A.lo_discount <= ?) AND (A.lo_quantity < ?) \n" +
                            "  AND (B.d_year = ?)";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        int[] arrayOfInts = {1,3,25,1993};

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(i + 1, arrayOfInts[i]); // the i index goes from the first "?" to the last, setting their values with the array value at that index. i + 1 because PreparedStatements indexes start from 1.
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we are talking specifically about sql, ensure you're not using direct string replacement, but rather we should be sanitizing the input data and using a prepared statement. By not going this route, you open yourself up to potential sql injection.

Here is a common example of the usage of prepared statements: https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/